# Novel where the speed of light is comparable to the speed of sound

Tags: story-identification, novel, speed-of-light

I am trying to discover the name of a book recommended to me by my school physics teacher some 48 years ago. The premise of the book is that the proponents visit a world where the speed of light is comparable to the speed of sound and how this affects all aspects of life.

Comment: Do you remember anything else about this you can [edit] in like how it affects life or did you just get told a basic overview?

Comment: I am fairly sure they only calculated the speed of speed much later. Thunder and lightning would not have been different entities.

Comment: More detail is needed; I can think of at least two potential answers to this, one of which was written as an accessible explanation to young people, the other a SF novel where the slow speed of light was an important plot point, but the story not intended as educational.

Comment: George Gamow's *Mr Tompkins in Wonderland* (1939) immediately comes to mind, though the speed of light there is a mere 10 mph.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - Mr Tompkins was one of the two I was thinking of, though I only had _Mr Tompkins in Paperback_.

Comment: You might also want to check out the video game [A Slower Speed of Light](http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/) MIT put out in 2013 for a more "hands on" experience of the subject.

Comment: @user14111 - funny, but he means definition 2:  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comparable

Comment: @user14111 Since when is light taking [amphetamines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphetamine)? What makes light's speed better than sound's? Why did you drop into Spanish for a word there? (See how pointless and irritating intentional misinterpretations can be?)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is [Mr. Tompkins in Wonderland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr_Tompkins) (1939). After attending a lecture on relativity the protagonist dreams that he enters a fantastical world where light moves at a *mere fraction* of the speed of sound.

> When he opened his eyes again, he found himself sitting not on a
> lecture room  bench but on one of the benches installed by the city
> for the convenience of  passengers waiting for a bus. It was a
> beautiful old city with medieval college  buildings lining the street.
> He suspected that he must be dreaming but to his  surprise there was
> nothing unusual happening around him; even a policeman  standing on
> the opposite corner looked as policemen usually do. The hands of the
> big clock on the tower down the street were pointing to five o’clock
> and the streets  were nearly empty. A single cyclist was coming slowly
> down the street and, as he  approached, Mr Tompkins’s eyes opened wide
> with astonishment. For the bicycle  and the young man on it were
> unbelievably shortened in the direction of the  motion, as if seen
> through a cylindrical lens. The clock on the tower struck five,  and
> the cyclist, evidently in a hurry, stepped harder on the pedals. Mr
> Tompkins did  not notice that he gained much in speed, but, as the
> result of his effort, he shortened  still more and went down the
> street looking exactly like a picture cut out of  cardboard.
>
> <sub><sup>[Archive.Org - Full Text available here](https://archive.org/stream/MrTompkinsInWonderlandMrTompkinsExploresTheAtom/tompkins_djvu.txt)</sup></sub>

Comment: That was my first thought, too, but the speed of light in the book is only 10 mph - far less than the speed of sound. Even bicycling introduces noticeable relativistic effects.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - Sound is mentioned on multiple occasions in the story though. "*Also, if you move, say in a car, to meet the sound propagating through the air, the 
velocity of the sound as measured in the car will be larger by the amount of your 
driving speed, or it will be correspondingly small if the sound is overtaking you. 
We call it the theorem of addition of velocities and it was always held to be self- 
evident.*", etc. Certainly it's mentioned enough that OP may have forgotten the difference in the intervening five decades

Comment: This sounds exactly like I remember, indeed the example given of the cyclist is one I remember him quoting.  Thank you very much, now I just need to find a copy!

Comment: @Valorum - You posted the same link twice.  The illustration one appears to go to the text.

Comment: You can read the whole text by following the link [here](https://archive.org/stream/MrTompkinsInWonderlandMrTompkinsExploresTheAtom/tompkins_djvu.txt) and view the illustrations [here](https://books.google.com.na/books?id=4843AAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @Valorum dit those links into the question

Answer (score 27):

This could be [*Redshift Rendezvous*](http://www.neverend.com/excerpt_redshift_rendezvous) by John E. Stith.  When the titular starship *Redshift* is in hyperspace, the artificial black hole at its core, combined with the reduction of lightspeed in hyperspace, means the speed of sound is a quick run, while the speed of light is only several times that figure.  Time dilation effects can vary noticeably between your head and your feet, you must wear a lifebelt to keep your nerve impulses fast enough to sustain life, and your watch will never agree with any other clock until you reset it after leaving hyperspace.

And in this bizarre environment, someone or something is killing people...

Comment: ... and this was the other one that I was thinking of!

Comment: What's a watch?

Comment: A watch is generally a small clock that you wear on your wrist or in your pocket (not all languages distinguish, so I'm assuming that's a serious question).

Comment: I'd guess that no one recommended _Redshift Rendezvous_ (1990) in 1970.

Comment: This was a fine story - but of course, not old enough.

Answer (score 18):

While this is clearly not the answer you're looking for, the Discworld novels by Terry Pratchett would fit the bill (if not for the recommendation being 48 years ago). In the Discworld, the speed of light is explicitly described (by the author) as being about the speed of sound, and perhaps less - my memory has dropped that particular detail.

Additionally, the speed of Dark is even greater, since that's how dark gets out of the way.

Comment: Whoa.  I missed the ~1970 recommendation date.  That's a good bit before *Redshift Rendezvous*, too...

Comment: While true in the description of disclight, relativistic effects are never touched on in the books. Not even in *The Science Of Discworld.*

Comment: There is some stuff that could be considered relativistic effects in Thief of Time when Lobsang and Lu-Tze slice their way closer to the wall. Blue/Red shifting and faster personal frames of reference for example.

Comment: There's some talk in one of the books that there must be another type of light that travels incredibly fast that allows them to see the light that is slowed down by magic, but it's not really looked into that deeply.

Comment: @Draco18s, there's at least a a brief mention, I think in Light Fantastic.  When that particularly nasty wizard tries to kill his superior with a thrown dagger, IIRC.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'd have to re read that one. In any case, the examples are far less prevalent and important than I'd consider necessary to answer the question. I feel that the slowness of disclight is more of a humor thing than mechanical. Ie "haha isn't that funny" a oppressed to "no, its literally like that." Remember that the explanation (a footnote!) was followed up by kingons and queenons (and possible annihilation when encountering republicons, if the character hadn't gotten thrown out of the bar).

Comment: @Draco18s - Well, sure, the slowness of disklight IS more of a humor thing. But what in the Discworld isn't?

Comment: I was always under the impression that the slow speed of light on the Discworld was a refraction-like effect, analogous to how light travels slowly through (say) diamond.

Comment: Wow. This StackExchange site is much more lenient compared to Physics StackExchange. On Physics SE, an answer that starts with "This is clearly not an answer..." would surely invite a comment that points out that then it should be a comment, not an answer. xD

Comment: @DvijMankad - When "Fantasy" is part of the site's title, you have to allow a certain amount of leeway when invoking reality.